# Wix - How to only remove the app root directory during uninstall

Tags: wix

Using Wix 3.5, Is there a way to limit the directories that are removed during an uninstall? Below is the structure I'm using:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="CommonAppDataSubFolder1" Name="SubFolder1">
          <Directory Id="CommonAppDataSubFolder2" Name="SubFolder2">
            <Directory Id="CommonAppDataSubFolder3" Name="SubFolder3">
              <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="My_App">
              </Directory>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I'd like to only remove the "APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" in this case during an uninstall. My application is an addon to another vendor's parent application. Addon developers are supposed to install to a specific directory but not remove the entire folder structure during uninstall. I'd like to preserve sub folders 1 through 3.

Thank You,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

WiX will not remove those directories if they are not empty.

Update:
In your case, if the directories are empty and you want to keep them on uninstall, I would suggest removing the directory structure from your installer. Instead, use a custom action to set a property that contains the installation directory, and then install to that directory. I think that may work (but haven't tested it).

Comment: Thanks Bryan - In some cases they may be empty. That is the root of my problem. I'm required to leave those parent folders there. My uninstaller should only remove my applications directory and not the parent application's plugin directory structure (which may be a series of empty folders).

Comment: @JeffJohnson, see the update to my answer. I haven't tested it though, but it's a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll check into that option.